# Simple way to extract value from HTML

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep, regular-expression, html

I have a very simple html file with a value inside. Value is 57 in this case.

```
<eta version="1.0"><value uri="/user/var/48/10391/0/0/12528" strValue="57" unit="%" decPlaces="0" scaleFactor="10" advTextOffset="0">572</value></eta>
```

What is an easy bash script way to extract and write in a variable? Is there a way to not even require a wget into a file as an intermediate step, so as not require to open and use a file where it is stored, but directly work with the wget?

To clarify, I could do a simple `wget`, save to a file and check the file for the value or is there an even more enhanced way to do the `wget` somewhere in RAM and not require an explicit file to be stored?

Thanks a million times, highly appreciated
Norbert

Comment: HTML is a subset of XML.  You need to read up on using an XML Reader in Linux, which is most likely why you were downvoted.

Comment: @eyoung100 [HTML5 is not XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39560454/4970442)

Answer (score 12):

You can extract a value in your example with `grep` and assign it to the variable in the following way

```
$ x=$(wget -0 - 'http://foo/bar.html' | grep -Po '<value.*strValue="\K[[:digit:]]*')
$ echo $x
57
```

Explanation:

- `$()`: command substitution
- `grep -P`: grep with Perl regexp enable
- `grep -o`: grep shows only matched **part** of the line
- `\K`: do not show in the output anything what was matched up to this point
- `wget -O -`: prints downloaded document to standard output (not to file)

However, for general approach it is better to use dedicated parser for html code.

Comment: what is \K doing can u explain

Comment: See updated edit. `\K` works only with `-P` option.

Comment: + 1 for \K using perl regex

Comment: +1 but since you're using `-P`, why not use `\d+` instead of `[[:digit:]]*`?

Comment: Nice explanations. No temp file would be nice.

Comment: i know it is a stupid question, but can you show how it would look like if I do a wget to a website....so there is no need to intermediate have a local file stored?

Comment: @njordan See the update, you just need to use `-O -` option with `wget` as in [terdon](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167656/80886) answer. The `-` means to use standard output for downloaded document, not a file.

Comment: one more question, it seems that [[:digit:]]* does only extract a integer value.....I did use the same great line to extract another parameter....that is float (e.g., 15,4) and it cuts at 15....what do I have to do to take the complete string in the "" as a float variable?

Comment: Try `grep -Po '<value.*strValue="\K[[:digit:]]*(,[[:digit:]]+){0,1}'`. The `{0,1}` means that group inside `()` can be present only zero or one time. So `57,11,22` will match `57,11`.

Comment: Should my last question not also work directly this way: grep -Po '<value.*strValue="\K[[:digit:]]*,[[:digit:]]
Assuming that there has to be float value with one ","

Also, isn't there a more simple way to just take out all found between the ""?

Comment: @njordan `grep -Po '<value.*strValue="\K[[:digit:]]*,[[:digit:]]` will fail if there is integer and in case of float it will match only first digit after `,`. If that is what you are looking for that's fine. And yes, there is very easy way to take everything between `""` with `awk`, in your case: `awk -F'"' '{print $6}'`, however you must guarantee, that your value is exactly at `6`th position.

Comment: Sorry, I have another usecase now....what if I need to take a STRING....so everything between "". Thanks

Comment: @njordan as I've said in last comment with `awk` that would be `awk -F'"' '{print $6}'`, just change 6 to string position. If you want `grep` then crucial regexp would be `"[^"]*"`, but the whole command would depend on specific case.

Answer (score 5):

I have no idea what `wget` you're talking about but I am guessing that you want to download the file. If so, yes, you can download it and parse it with no intermediate temp file:

```
$ value=$(wget -O - http://example.com/file.html | grep -oP 'strValue="\K[^"]+')
$ echo $value
57
```

Comment: Yes, you are right `\d+` is shorter, also `[^"]+` is better because value inside `""` probably(?) doesn't need to be numerical.

Answer (score 3):

1. Apart from the `wget -O - ...` technique, you can also use `curl -Ss ...` to avoid the hassle of a temporary file.
2. The following illustrates the use of `pup` (https://github.com/ericchiang/pup), which supports a CSS-based query language.

a) To extract the "text" value of the `<value>` tag:

```
pup 'value text{}'  # yields 572
```

b) To extract the value of the strValue attribute of the `<value>` tag:

```
pup 'value attr{strvalue}' # yields 57
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cat input | grep -o strValue=".*" | sed 's/strValue=//g' | sed 's/"//g'
```

Comment: Useless use of cat and doesn't work anyway. If you really want to involve `sed` try `sed 's/.*strValue="\([[:digit:]]*\).*/\1/' file`.

Comment: Yeah, i tried..

Comment: I suck at everything.

Comment: No, you just need some practise and you have very good questions, I like especially this one: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159489/80886 for obvious reason. BTW, it was not me who downvoted.

Comment: I't doesn't matter who down voted, i don't really care about internet points that much :).